# Characteristic disks in $S^2 \times S^2$ for knots

Tags: knot-theory, homology, 4-manifolds

I'm studying the article [Genera and degrees of Torus Knots in $\mathbb{CP}^2$](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218216509007439) and I ended up with a question.
We know that every knot is slice (i.e. bounds properly embedded smooth disk) in $S^2 \times S^2 \setminus \mathbb{B}^4$ and so we can study the homology class of those disks. For example, by using lemma 3.2 contained [Torus knots that cannot be untied by twisting](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2098250_Torus_knots_that_cannot_be_untied_by_twisting), it can be proven that the torus knot $T(2,11)$ bounds a disk $\Delta$ whose homology class is
$ [\Delta] = -2\alpha + 8 \beta$, with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ the standard generators of $H_2(S^2 \times S^2 \setminus \mathbb{B}^4)$; this disk is characteristic.
My question is: For every torus knot $K$, is there a properly embedded disk in $S^2 \times S^2 \setminus \mathbb{B}^4$ whose homology class in $H_2$ is characteristic and with boundary $K$? In case of an affective answer, how can I find such disk the torus knot $T(4,5)$? Please note that the above cited lemma $3.2$ cannot be used for the torus knot $T(4,5)$